# Mysql split date cells?

Tags: mysql

i have

table test

```
column1
--------------------------------
name1 2017:01-01
name2 2017:01-02
--------------------------------
```

I want to put them in two columns how do i do that? Like this.

```
name        -        date
--------------------------------
name1       -        2017-01-01
name2       -        2017-01-02
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong its like this. Some times I have a name in the cells and sometimes not like this and the date format is different.

```
name
--------------------------------
name1 2017-03-26 21:35:26
name2 2017-01-02 20:10:02
      2017-01-01 15:30:05
--------------------------------
```

what I want is

```
name      -      date
--------------------------------
name1     -      2017-03-12 21:35:26
name2     -      2017-01-02 20:10:02
          -      2017-01-01 15:30:05
--------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `LEFT/RIGHT`:

```
SELECT LEFT(column1, LENGTH(column1)-10) AS name
   ,STR_TO_DATE(RIGHT(column1, 10), '%Y:%m-%d') AS `date`
FROM tab;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4c02df116c110c1132c863b54ffb9d26)**

Comment: Nice, but you might want to add something the handle the colon between year and month e.g.   SELECT LEFT(column1, LENGTH(column1)-11), REPLACE(RIGHT(column1, 10),':','-') FROM tab;